# How to organize food containers better?

Tags: kitchen, storage, container

We have plenty plastic storage containers for food leftovers, travel snacks, work lunches etc... Currently there's two cube drawers of Tupperware style containers.  Oftentimes the lids get separated  or its tricky to find what we're looking for.  Who has a better way of organizing these things in a small kitchen ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just neatly stack them into drawers (They're fairly cheap and you can buy some small ones) or into shelves? I can see there is space for more shelves in the drawer-type thing you are using. Any thin metal ones should do...